# select2 not responsive, width larger than container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with the width of a select2 dropdown in my ASP.NET page. When I try to view the page with the Chrome emulator of devices screen, the select2 is larger than the containing div, and on the right it goes out of the screen. I saw with code inspection that it adds automatically a style attribute `style="width: 498px;"` in the `<span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--bootstrap select2-container--below">` element that I did not set anywhere. The only operation that I did is to set `$("#ContentPlaceHolderContent_mySelect").select2();` in the document.ready function(). My select2 dropdown is contained in a block:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label col-md-3">Select structure</label>
   <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-9">
      <select class="form-control" id="mySelect" runat="server"></select>

   </div>
</div>
```

How can I remove that style="width" option?

Comment: Setting its inital width to 100% should solve this `$('#mySelect').select2({ width: '100%' });`

Comment: @LarsBeck This comment should be marked as best answer :-P

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Select2 adds class `.select2`. You can override what script does using css.
Here I'm set select2 to have `100% width`, using `!important`. If I would not do that select2 would have 24px width.

You can further customize other classes that `select2` generates using some principle.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#mySelect").select2();
});
```

```css
.select2 {
width:100%!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label col-md-3">Select structure</label>
   <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-9">
      <select class="form-control" id="mySelect" runat="server"></select>

   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 38):

This works for me:

```
$('select').select2({
    width: '100%'
});
```

and add CSS:

```
.select2-selection { overflow: hidden; }
.select2-selection__rendered { white-space: normal; word-break: break-all; }
```

Add to CSS "!important" if you need.

Comment: I didn't even need the CSS. Setting the option in the select2 initialization alone was sufficient.

Answer (score 5):

**Getting Overflow?** **Do it with JS also**

Using CSS width:100% sometimes get scrolling issue if some elements have overflow property. I would recommend using js also.

Add below js

```
 $('select').select2({
        width: '100%'
 });
```

Add below CSS

```
.select2-selection { overflow: hidden; }
.select2-selection__rendered { white-space: normal; word-break: break-all; }
```

/*Copied from already given :) */

Answer (score 3):

try use dropdownParent

```
$('#mySelect2').select2({
  dropdownParent: $('#myModal')
});
```

https://select2.org/dropdown#dropdown-placement

Answer (score 2):

if you are using bootstrap ,use the below style

```
.form-group > .select2-container {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all add Select2 class **.select2** in select tag and used these CSS.

```
.select2-container{
        width: 100% !important;
    }
    .control-label {
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `!important`, you just can override it with `max-width` like:

```
.select2{
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<span>` with the `.select2` class is created by the Select2 plugin just after creation a new select2 on a given `<select>`.

To make this `span.select2` element responsive, we may have some possibilities, such as:

1. Use a % width (either on the original  before creating the select2 element, or in the select2 [width](https://select2.org/appearance#container-width) configuration option).
2. Override via CSS (for example when we use `@media()` queries). Note that this may affect the plugin's functionality or display.

For the 2nd one, we can use the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) (`+`) with the `!important` on the width value to style our select2's `<span>`, since normally the select2's span is created and inserted right after our `<select>`.

An example below:

```css
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  select.my-x-select + span.select2 {
    width: 200px !important;
  }
}
```

**Note:** `select` and `span` element selectors aren't needed, `@media` as an example use case.

Comment: Feedback for the negative voting? Was the `!important` appearance?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this problem in the future. I have found a solution in a [Git Issue](https://github.com/t0m/select2-bootstrap-css/issues/42)

It seems that for some reason the placeholder can grow bigger than the parent element, therefore breaking the layout. The easy fix for this is:

```
input[placeholder] { width: 100% !important; }
```